# searching for symbols in sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, select, escaping

i need to search for and of these `! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) '\` symbols in within a field content sqlite database, i am using the following sql string

```
Select ID From Tasks Where '--' || tasks || '--' ||  note || '--'  like '%! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) ""%'
```

or i tried this

```
Select ID From Tasks Where task LIKE '[!] [@] [#] [$] [%] [^] [&] [*] [(] [)] ''%'
```

but the search does not return any result. For the field `task` some of the content are

1. `Today's tasks` or
2. `here are some wildcards ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) '` or
3. `Some brakest are [ ] { } ( )`

so if i search item one as a whole, i should get it or if i search for `! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) '`, i should get item 2. etc

if i serah within the field passing some of the wildcards within the text or all in the same order, i should get the row contain the value

I know some  of the symbols have meaning in sqlite sql, so how do i escape all or any of these characters in an sql query string

Comment: if you are down voting, why dont you take some seconds to explain why? it the question not a good one?

Comment: Your description is rather vague. Please show some example data that should and should not be found.

Comment: @CL, i have updated the question, pls have  look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, strings in SQL are enclosed in single quotes; if you want to write a string containing single quotes, you have to escape them by doubling them:

```
SELECT ID FROM Tasks WHERE task = 'Today''s tasks'
```

To avoid this, most languages allow you to use parameters:

```py
db.execute("SELECT ID FROM Tasks WHERE task = ?", [ "Today's tasks" ])
```

---

Second, the `LIKE` operator interprets the `%` and `_` characters specially.
To use these characters without their special meaning, you can use the [`ESCAPE` clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) to specify a character that escapes `%`, `_`, and itself:

```
SELECT ID FROM Tasks WHERE task LIKE '%! @@ # $ @% ^ & * ( ) ''%' ESCAPE '@'
```

This escaping is completely independent from the SQL string quoting; you stil you have to use even if you're using parameters:

```py
db.execute("SELECT ID FROM Tasks WHERE task LIKE ? ESCAPE '@'",
           [ "%! @@ # $ @% ^ & * ( ) '%" ])
```

---

Third, the `GLOB` operator does not have special escape characters;
you use special characters literally, you have to use them in peculiar ways.
From the documentation:

> Globbing rules:
>
> - `'*'`       Matches any sequence of zero or more characters.
> - `'?'`       Matches exactly one character.
> - `[...]`      Matches one character from the enclosed list of characters.
> - `[^...]`     Matches one character not in the enclosed list.
>
> With the `[...]` and `[^...]` matching, a `']'` character can be included
>   in the list by making it the first character after `'['` or `'^'`.  A
>   range of characters can be specified using `'-'`.  Example:
>   `"[a-z]"` matches any single lower-case letter.  To match a `'-'`, make
>   it the last character in the list.
>
> Hints: to match `'*'` or `'?'`, put them in `"[]"`.  Like this:
>
> `abc[*]xyz`        Matches `"abc*xyz"` only

Comment: i found out that `GLOB` is case sensitive, so this is the reason am using `LIKE`. so i only escape `@,!` the other characters can be left as is? If am search for `%! # $ ^ & * ( ) '`, then i dont need to escape any of these characters right

Comment: Why are you mentioning `@,!`? The special characters for `LIKE` are `%` and `_`, and whatever character you choose as escape character.

Comment: @CJ thank you very much. so even if i do this `'%@! @@ @# $ @% @^ @& @* @( @) ''%'`, it dosent have any negetive effects right

Comment: You should not try to escape characters that don't need escaping; some DBs might insert the escape character itself.

Comment: @CJ thank you very much once again. I tried this statement `SELECT ID FROM Tasks WHERE task LIKE '%Today''s Task%' `, and it failed to find the item

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
Select ID From Contacts Where (email || mobile || main || other) GLOB '*[!@#$%^&*()\]*'
```

Comment: thanks, your codes seems to find any of the symbols. but the issue is that i need to search for any or all of the symbols within field. the search is not constructed by me, but by the end user. so he may try to serahc for `$ % ^` or `@ ) (`. when i search for all `! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) \`, i dont get results.